# Sample .travis.yml for Cocoapods based iOS projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, travis-ci, xctool

I have this very simple iOS project. It's using Cocoapods for dependency management, and includes *AFNetworking* as one of its dependency. Currently, my project code is just doing a simple http GET request and the test (written using *Specta*) checks if it succeeds.

Now, I'm trying to CI it with Travis-CI. I've already checked out [xctool CI tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/xctool#continuous-integration) and [objective-c CI manual from Travis-CI](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/), my current **.travis-ci.yml** is:

```
language: objective-c
xcode_project: Foobar.xcodeproj
xcode_schema: Foobar
```

The last output lines from CI console are:

> The command "echo "  Check out our documentation for more information: http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/objective-c/"" exited with 0.
>       Done. Your build exited with 0.

It seems to me that nothing has been tested. There's definitely something wrong with my .travis.yml. So my questions are:

1. There's a .xworkspace file generated by Cocoapods, so which one do I use in .travis.yml, the .xcodeproj or .workspace?
2. Which scheme to use, `Foobar` or `FoobarTests`?
3. Do I still need to additionally specify `script: xctool ...` command?
4. From [xctool CI tutorial](https://github.com/facebook/xctool#continuous-integration):

   > Click the + button and add each dependency to the project. CocoaPods will appear as a static library named Pods.

I cannot add `Pods` project as a whole, but rather each independent projects. Is this right? And does it mean that I have to do each time I add a library to Podfile?

Comment: I can say xcworkspace and FoobarTests for 1 and 2, but thats about all I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of @Schemetrical 's comment above and, a review of my .travis.yml. There turns out to be a typo: `xcode_schema` should be `xcode_scheme`...

So, as a result, here's my **.travis.yml**:

```
language: objective-c
xcode_workspace: Foobar.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: Foobar
```

For vanilla Cocoapods generated project/workspace, there's no such scheme called `FoobarTests`, but rather only one named `Foobar`. So this should answer questions 1-3 above.

For question 4, I added only two additional targets: `Pods-Foobar` and `Pods-FoobarTests`, and they should contain all dependencies from your Podfile.